# Classic ASP VBScript need dropin replacement for MyConn.Execute( query )

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic, garbage-collection

I have a site running on ASP VBScript, and the original code never closes a DB connection.  It opens connections as part of "startup" for any given page, then does whatever it does and stops -- but never explicitly closes connections.  This is now causing problems where  things are crashing at the web server level -- presumably from the lack of garbage collection.

So I want to make a function that acts as a drop-in replacement for all the MyConn.Execute( sqlQuery ) commands throughout the site.  I've found some good candidates, but none of them seem to quite work.  The most promising appears to be the code below, but when I try to actually use the recordset returned I get an error.

```vbs
Function GetRS(strSQL)
  'this function returns a disconnected RS

  'Set some constants
  Const adOpenStatic = 3    
  Const adUseClient = 3
  Const adLockBatchOptimistic = 4 

  'Declare our variables
  Dim oConn
  Dim strSQL
  Dim oRS

  'Open a connection
  Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  oConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;User=foo;Password=bar;Database=baz"
  oConn.Open

  'Create the Recordset object
  Set oRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  oRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient

  'Populate the Recordset object with a SQL query
  oRS.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

  'Disconnect the Recordset
  Set oRS.ActiveConnection = Nothing

  'Return the Recordset
  Set GetRS = oRS

  'Clean up...
  oConn.Close
  oRS.Close
  Set oConn = Nothing
  Set oRS = Nothing
End Function

'call the function
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Authors"   
set RS = GetRS(strSQL)
```

(source: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134116/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080101-1.shtml)

Here's my test code:

```
Set rs = GetRS( "SELECT `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE `id`=123" )
x = rs( "first_name" )
response.write x
```

I get the error:

```
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'

Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

/test.asp, line 25
```

Using an ordinal -- rs(0) -- returns the same error.

Looks like an empty recordset to me, but it's a legit Query that does return a record.

Does anyone know why this isn't working, or can point me to other code that will do the job? (Especially with practical usage examples, which the 4guys article lacks.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661430/classic-asp-disconnected-recordsets-issue

The answer there talks about the possibility of copying the data to a newly-created recordset.  Hmmm...

Comment: It appears what I really need is a way truly COPY a recordset, rather than merely pointing to it.

Comment: Could it be because you close the recordset at the end of the sub: `oRS.Close`?

Comment: I believe that's the issue, but it's also the POINT of what I'm doing.  I've seen similar code all over the place that claims this creates a "disconnected recordset" -- meaning you (supposedly) CAN close the recordset.  In theory we're making a COPY of the recordset, which means I should be able to close the original recordset after closing it.  I believe what is *actually* happening is the  = creates a pointer rather than a copy. But it seems clear that this type of thing USED to work, because I see it a lot on old ASP sites.

Comment: Hmm... maybe I'm overthinking it. I *want* a recordset when I'm done, so it doesn't really matter if I'm copying or pointing to the existing Recordset. The important bit is that I'm closing the DB Connection.  Still strikes me as weird that the code used to work but for some reason doesn't any more. (I've seen half a dozen sites describe this method).  Thanks, this should work for me.

Comment: @StephenR When you close a Recordset it means you have done with it, you can't achieve any fields anymore. It's by design and there's no exceptions, you probably remember wrong. On the other hand, [the code](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080101-1.shtml) you use is not well-tested I think. A local variable shadows the function parameter `strSQL`. It does not even work with a local `On Error Resume Next` statement because of a syntax error. As you are aware at the moment, returning recordsets without closing them is OK.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin I kind of agree but not fully, you see the `oRS.Close` happens after the recordset has been returned from the function *(`oRS` and `RS` are two separate object variables only `oRS` is closed)*. This has worked for me in the past using a SQL Server provider, so the problem is likely a provider one.

Comment: @Lankymart No. There's no `Return` statement in VBScript, and since there's no `Exit Function` right after `Set GetRS = oRS` recordset returned after `End Function`, so it was a closed Recordset object.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin again not correct VBScript does have a `Return` statement it's the functions name, `Set GetRS = oRS` is setting the object variable `RS` to `oRS`, but unlike a `Return` statement it still allows clean up / local variable manipulation afterwards.

Comment: @Lankymart So it's not like `Return`s in other languages, what's wrong. I do not understand what you're trying to prove. BTW When you assign an object to a new variable, a copy is not created in the memory, it's the object reference you set new variable. That's the reason Recordset object has a `Clone` method for example.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin all I'm saying is I've done it before, try it yourself. I've even used that exact 4guysfromrolla article and they have never steered me wrong. I'm going off memory here, only way I'll conclusively prove it is writing something but I'm not on my laptop at the moment.

Comment: @Lankymart OK. You can reach me at the email address on my profile if you want to show me something.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin like I said, I'm fairly sure it's a provider issue note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036443/692942) from a similar question for VB6. The OP is trying to use MySQL to create a disconnected recordset and getting no result, whereas the author of the answer posted a solution they have used for years with SQL Server.

Comment: @Lankymart It does not matter SQL Server or MySQL, the problem is here a closed recordset. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036443/692942) an open Recordset object returned, of course it should work :/

Comment: FYI this is Classic ASP. I've seen the VB6 script, but it does a bunch of stuff that doesn't just run on classic

Comment: As best I can tell, the "return" on this function doesn't make a copy of the recordset — merely a pointer. Thus when I close the recordset after returning it, it also closes it on the external variable I assigned the function results to.

Comment: Actually got this working... sort of.  The code works pretty well as long as I don't close the RS, *except* that it sometimes (but not always) crashes when I do a "rs.eof" test.  Works fine if I do the query manually, but recordsets from the above function trigger the error for some reason. Not sure why the function-created recordsets would be different. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that a a Recordset is tied to the datasource. When you execute a query, by default, the client (your program) doesn't get the entire contents of the query, but will wait until you actually request the data. That way, you can choose a specific page size, page offset etc. to efficiently select rows from the database without transferring potentially millions of rows over the wire.

As a side-effect of this, if you close the database connection, you will no longer be able to use the Recordset. You must leave the connection open until you are done with it. In the same way, closing the Recordset itself will stop you from being able to interact with it further.

You have two options: copy the data out of the Recordset into your own variables/arrays before closing, or use a different technique to manage your connection. I'll talk about the latter option here.

There is technique which will allow you to open the DB connection once, and ensure it is closed properly by VBScript when it terminates.

```
Class DbConnectionManager
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        oConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;User=foo;Password=bar;Database=baz"
        oConn.Open
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        oConn.Close
    End Sub
End Class

Dim connMgr : Set connMgr = New DbConnectionManager
```

This code snippet is untested, but the general principle is that you start your program by defining a class and creating an instance of it. When a class instance is created, `Class_Initialize` is called, and when your program ends (or the instance gets removed and garbage-collected), then `Class_Terminate` will be called. That means `oConn.Close` should always be called before your program ends, even in the event of an error.

This is a very basic example of how classes work, but you could actually extend the class further and insert your Execute functions into the class itself to encapsulate the database connection details for easier maintenance. If you haven't used classes in VBScript yet but you have a basic understanding of how Object-Oriented programming works, I would highly recommend you try that.

Bonus extra: It looks like you're passing in raw SQL strings. To avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities, don't build your SQL queries dynamically. Instead, use ADO and parameters so any user-created content can be safely passed into the query without security risks. [How do I run a parameterized SQL query in classic ASP? And is it secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579687/how-do-i-run-a-parameterized-sql-query-in-classic-asp-and-is-it-secure) W3Schools also has a section on how to use ADO.

Comment: Oh, believe me, parameterization is high on the Do Next list, but first I have to stop the site from straight up crashing under moderate load. ;-)

Comment: Just so I know I'm understanding this, could you give a quick usage example?  Again, this needs to be a mass copy/replace of "MyConn.Execute(", so hopefully avoiding "and then when you're done using the record set...".  I'm not at my computer at the moment to try this, but it looks awesome.

Comment: Ah... I see.  I still have to make a new method within the class to actually run the query, then call that method. Yes?

Comment: It depends on whether you need to guarantee that your Recordsets get closed as well as the DB connection when the program ends (it shouldn't matter, but maybe it does in your environment). If you don't, then just make sure the above example is put into an include file and have it executed before you make any DB calls. With that in place, you can write your functions to execute queries and do whatever you want, provided your Recordset remains open until you have retrieved all the data that you need.

Comment: Consider your code tested.  It worked great.  I assume by "It doesn't matter" you're suggesting that (usually) closing a connection also closes any related Recordsets?

Comment: Marking this as Answer despite the fact that, technically, it doesn't answer the question.  It does, however, solve the *problem* I had.  May have to follow up on that true Replacement that handles closing the Recordset as well.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, closing connections should close Recordsets without any detrimental effects, because Recordsets are 100% client-side and will die with the program. With regards to further improvements, you can actually use a similar technique for handling Recordsets if you need to have them auto-closed, by wrapping them in classes too. Some people even exploit this 'always execute Class_Terminate` behaviour to write simple try-catch logic in a language that doesn't natively support it. (I'm not sure if I'd recommend that, though!) Any more specific questions, just fire away!

Comment: Not sure if I'm misunderstanding you, but "client side" to me means "in the web browser". This is definitely server-side ASP. The browser never sees the raw recordset, just the HTML output of the script.

Comment: I played a bit with containing recordsets in a class, but I'm having trouble seeing how I could do it in a way that actual usage would be **exactly the same** — especially things like rs.EOF tests.

Comment: While the program is indeed serving a web page, In the context I'm talking about, the client is actually the VBScript code and the server is the database.
In the simplest implementation, all you have to do is carry on using raw Resultsets as you usually would, but in addition to that, you create a new instance of a class that's configured to close the Recordset when the program ends or the instance is set to nothing. As I said, I'm not sure if that will be necessary, so I would recommend you test it first and see. Let me know your findings.

Comment: $BoffinbraiN -- long term follow-up:  It's been working well for me. Seems to handle the recordsets well without having to implement a recordset class.